# Android Q - The swipe back gesture behavior is not intuitive when custom animation between fragments is vertical and not horizontal

Tags: android, swipe, gesture, android-10.0

I'm already testing my apps on emulator with targetSdkVersion 29 to test the new swipe back gesture with Android Q.

I'm facing an issue when I have an animation transition between fragments from bottom to top (enter) and from top to bottom (exit).

The swipe back is always from left-to-right but in this case this is not really intuitive.

In the near future, it will be possible to have a swipe back from top-to-bottom ?
At this time, is there a way to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Imho, even if there would be a way to set a custom system swipe back gesture for your app (but which is fortunately not possible), you would:

- confuse your users (if you for example block the default swipe back gesture and provide another custom one in your app. You would also have to imitate the system's back animation which I would definitely not recommend to do.)
- set a new gesture which is not intuitive, since it's different than the system back gesture and which is also ergonomically not efficient (e.g. try to perform a swipe back from top (border) to-bottom with your thumb; you could also accidentally trigger the status bar.)

Therefore, I don't think that there will be a top-to-bottom swipe back system gesture.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think the same but I have seen in iOs a swipe back gesture which begins with left-to-right and finishes with a top-to-bottom. It could be interesting to do something like that.